# Comparing numbers in a column

Tags: bash, awk

I am familiar with comparing numbers in a row using bash, but what if I wanted to compare columns? Like if i had a file with

```
4 2 5 7
6 1 3 8
```

And I want to find the largest out of each column

```
6 2 5 8
```

How can I do this using awk?

Comment: Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: There's surely a bash/awk solution for your problem. That being said, why would you tackle such a problem in bash in the first place?! It's just the wrong language for anything but simple 10-line scripts. Sure, you can write more complex code (I did), but it's so much harder than using Python, Perl, TCL, Lua, etc.

Comment: @unxnut no, the number of columns is not fixed

Comment: Is it the same number of fields in each record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in a file called "data":

```
$ awk '{for(j=1;j<=NF;++j){max[j]=(max[j]>$j)?max[j]:$j};mNF=mNF>NF?mNF:NF} END{for(j=1;j<=mNF;++j)printf " " max[j]; print "" }' data
 6 2 5 8
```

Or, with different output formatting:

```
$ awk '{for(j=1;j<=NF;++j){max[j]=(max[j]>$j)?max[j]:$j};mNF=mNF>NF?mNF:NF} END{for(j=1;j<=mNF;++j)print "max of column " j "=" max[j]}' data
max of column 1=6
max of column 2=2
max of column 3=5
max of column 4=8
```

The body of the above `awk` program consists of:

```
{ for(j=1;j<=NF;++j) {max[j]=(max[j]>$j)?max[j]:$j};mNF=mNF>NF?mNF:NF }
```

This loop is run for every line in the input file.  The loop runs through every column (field) in that input line from 1 to the number of fields (`NF`).  For each column, it checks to see if the current value is greater than the previous maximum.  If it is, it updates the value in the `max` array.

Comment: +1: OP can use `END{for(j=1;j<=NF;++j)printf "%s%s",max[j],(j==NF?"\n":FS)}'` to print according to the desired output.

Comment: @jaypal, or even `END {for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) printf "%s ",max[j]; print ""}` -- a bit less tricky

Comment: @glennjackman Absolutely .. I am just more inclined more towards job security! `;)`.

Comment: you need fix it with no-fix columns. `awk '{for(j=1;j<=NF;++j)max[j]=(max[j]>$j)?max[j]:$j;mNF=mNF>NF?mNF:NF} END{for(j=1;j<=mNF;++j) printf max[j] FS; print RS }' file`

Comment: @BMW Thanks! That is a nice generalization.  I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bash solution using arrays:

```
max=();
while read -a line ; do 
    for ((i=0; i<${#line[@]} ; i++)) ; do
        ((line[i]>max[i])) && max[i]=${line[i]}
    done
done < input
echo "${max[@]}"
```